# why I got this.http.get(...).subscribe is not a function in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

My code is

```
    import 'rxjs/Rx';
    ...
    let _this = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        _this.http[method](url, data, {
            headers: headers
        })
        .toPromise()
        .then(
            (data) => {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error => {
                reject(error);
            }
        );
    });
```

The "subscribe" not come from my code, looks like it's angular original something.

Error message:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.http.get(...).subscribe is not a function
```

Comment: You don't need `let _this = this` if you use `(resolve, reject) => {` instead. You don't need `new Promise(...)` when you use `toPromise()`. Just `return this.http[method](url, data, {
            headers: headers
        })
        .toPromise();` should do the same.

Comment: Definitely agreed with Günter! Regarding your error, which version of Angular2 do you use? I made a try with beta17 but I don't have the error: https://plnkr.co/edit/TPy2UVEE8EE4MLTlf8yc?p=preview.

Comment: Becoz I have few steps in "then", install angular with ionic beta

Answer (score 2):

You are combating the **Angular2** initiative of porting over from the `promise` based asynchronous paradigm to the `reactive-extensions` alternative. Instead of using a promise, use the `subscribe` instead:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
...
invoke<T>(onNext: (data: T) => void, onError: (error: any) => any) {
    this.http[method](url, data, {
        headers: headers
    })
    .map(response => response.json() as T)
    .subscribe(onNext, onError);
});
```

I wrote a blog post about this too.

https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/angular-2-http/